# Can finding a witness be NP-hard even if we already know there is one?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, search-problem

The common examples of NP-hard problems (clique, 3-SAT, vertex cover, etc.) are of the type where we don't know whether the answer is "yes" or "no" beforehand.

Suppose that we have a problem in which the we know the answer is yes, furthermore we can verify a witness in polynomial time.

Can we then always find a witness in polynomial time?  Or can this "search problem" be NP-hard?

Comment: It's unlikely. Can be PPAD-hard though.

Comment: I don't know if this is a coincidence or not, but this blogpost was posted today: [_... a reminder that total search problems are not NP-complete_](http://paulwgoldberg.blogspot.com.au/2015/03/tutorial-talks-and-reminder-that-total.html) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TFNP is the class of multivalued functions with values that are polynomially verified and guaranteed to exist.

There exists a problem in TFNP that is FNP-complete if and only if NP = co-NP, see Theorem 2.1 in:

Nimrod Megiddo and Christos H. Papadimitriou. 1991. On total functions, existence theorems and computational complexity. Theor. Comput. Sci. 81, 2 (April 1991), 317-324. DOI: [10.1016/0304-3975(91)90200-L](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(91)90200-L)

and the references [6] and [11] within. PDF available [here](http://theory.stanford.edu/~megiddo/pdf/papadimX.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't always find a solution in polynomial time, even if you know there is a solution.

According to Khanna, Linial, and Safra [1] (see the 3rd paragraph), it follows already from the classic 1972 work by Karp that that coloring a 3-colorable graph with 3 colors is NP-hard. (Their work extends this to show that 4-coloring 3-colorable graphs is still NP-hard).

Note that this does not contradict [the answer by Rahul Savani](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/40509/472). This is because for all binary relations $P$ in FNP, we must be able to verify in polynomial time if $P(x,y)$ is in the relation. Given that deciding if a 3-colorable graph with 3 colors is NP-complete, it is unlikely the problem of finding a 4-coloring in a 3-colorable graph is in FNP since we cannot verify the validity of the input $x$ in polynomial time. Thus, there is no contradiction to the Megiddo-Papadimitriou result.

---

[1] [Khanna, Sanjeev, Nathan Linial, and Shmuel Safra. "On the hardness of approximating the chromatic number." Theory and Computing Systems, 1993., Proceedings of the 2nd Israel Symposium on the. IEEE, 1993.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.75.2329&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If an NP-relation is NP-hard with respect to yes-answer-only

co-nondeterministic polynomial-time Turing reductions, then $\: NP = coNP \;$.

Proof:

If an NP-relation is NP-hard with respect to yes-answer-only

co-nondeterministic polynomial-time Turing reductions, then:

Let $R$ be such a hard relation, and let $M'$ be a yes-answer-only co-nondeterministic polynomial-time Turing reduction from $SAT$ to $R$. $\:$ Let $M$ be the coNP algorithm given by:

$\;$ Attempt to parse the alleged anti-[certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)#Verifier-based_definition) into an inner certificate and responses.

$\;$ If that fails then output YES, else attempt to run $M'$ on the inner anti-certificate by giving

$\;$ the same response as was given before for repeat-queries and using the responses from

$\;$ the (outer) anti-certificate for all other oracle queries. $\:$ If $M'$ would make more distinct

$\;$ queries than the number of responses or any of its queries would not be related by $R$ to

$\;$ that query's response or $M'$ would output YES, the $M$ outputs YES, else $M$ outputs NO.

Since being an oracle for $R$ just imposes independent conditions on the oracle's responses

and $M'$ is a yes-answer-only reduction, the query-response pairs produced by $M'$

and a valid anti-certificate can always be extended to an oracle for $R$, so $M$ solves $SAT\hspace{-0.02 in}$.

Thus $\: SAT\in coNP \;$.

Since $SAT$ is $NP$-hard with respect to deterministic polynomial-time reductions, $\: NP\subseteq coNP \;$.

By symmetry, $\: coNP \subseteq NP \;$. $\;\;\;\;$ Thus $\: NP = coNP \;$. 

Therefore, if an NP-relation is NP-hard with respect to yes-answer-only

co-nondeterministic polynomial-time Turing reductions, then $\: NP = coNP \;$.

Comment: I dont understand any of this. Can you define a "yes-answer-only 
co-nondeterministic polynomial-time Turing reduction", an "anti-certificate", and also clarify what $M'$ is exactly ("reduction from R SAT" makes no sense to me)?

Comment: A "yes-answer-only co-nondeterministic polynomial-time Turing reduction" is a [coNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_machine) oracle machine whose oracle is for what the reduction is to, such that it will never query the oracle on an input for which there is no polynomial-size string that the query is related to by $R$. $\:$ (continued ...) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: (... continued) $\:$ An anti-certificate is the analogue of a [certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)#Verifier-based_definition), with YES and NO interchanged. $\:$ $M'$ is the reduction mentioned in the sentence that introduced $M'$. $\:$ (I fixed the typo at the end of that sentence.) $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 1):

This depends slightly on the precise interpretation of your question, but I think your scenario can be generically described as a problem 'COMPUTE Y' where given some universally fixed polynomial time algorithm $T$ and polynomial $p$, on input $\langle x, 1^n \rangle$, output a string $y \in \{0,1\}^{p(n)}$, such that $T(x,y,1^n)$ outputs 1, and $y$ always exists for all possible $x$.

One question then might be whether a polynomial time algorithm for 'COMPUTE Y' implies $P = NP$

In this case, assume you can solve (say) 3SAT in polynomial time with a constant number of calls to an oracle that solves 'COMPUTE Y', i.e. some algorithm $A$ where $A(\phi) = 1$ iff $\phi$ is satisfiable, $A(\phi)=0$ otherwise. Flip the output bit to get $\bar{A}$, an algorithm where $\bar{A}(\phi) = 0$ iff $\phi$ is satisfiable and $\bar{A}(\phi) = 1$ if $\phi$ is unsatisfiable.

Convert this algorithm $\bar{A}$ (which uses an oracle for 'COMPUTE Y') into a nondeterministic algorithm (that uses no oracles) by simply replacing each oracle call with a nondeterministic guess of $y$ that you can check with a call to $T$. Now you have a nondeterministic algorithm which successfully decides unsatisfiable 3CNF instances, so $NP = coNP$

As an aside, if $NP = coNP$, that implies that all $NP$ complete problems (like $k$-clique or 3SAT) have slight variations whose decision problem is easy (always 'yes') yet whose search version is $NP$-hard

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple argument that the ability to find a witness in polynomial time would imply P=NP:

1. Assume that we have a poly-time algorithm for finding a witness to any YES-instance of some NP-complete problem. Then there exist absolute constants $k$ and $c$ such that when run on a valid input of size $n$, the algorithm completes after at most $n^k + c$ steps and reports a valid witness. (Note that on an invalid input -- specifically, a NO-instance -- the algorithm's behaviour is undefined. It may detect a contradiction and abort, or produce an invalid witness, or even loop forever.)
2. Analyse the algorithm to derive concrete values for $k$ and $c$. (Loose upper bounds are fine.)
3. To solve an arbitrary instance of the problem in poly-time:

   1. *Guess* that the instance is a YES-instance, and run the poly-time witness-finding algorithm on it for at most $n^k+c+1$ steps.
   2. If the algorithm aborts early, or runs for $n^k+c+1$ steps, report "NO".
   3. Otherwise check the witness it produced. This can be done in poly-time. If the witness is valid, report "YES", otherwise report "NO".